# how to increase the number of Maximum Connections in Faye while using thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin, faye

When I start Faye using thin server, it says

> > Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Chromeo)
> >
> > Maximum connections set to 1024
> >
> > Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop

May i know how to increase the number of Maximum Connection??

Answer (score 0):

Start server using the thin command, like here: https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#running-the-app-with-thin.

And you can set a config file with the `-C`option, and define everything you want, take a look at https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/#configuration-files